# Declarar procedure en mysql con variable

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `insertarProv` ( IN prec float, IN nom varchar( 15 ) )
BEGIN
set @idP := select ID_Prov from proveedor Where Nombre_Prov = nom;
INSERT INTO Relacion_Prov_Prod (Precio,ID_Prov,ID_Prod)
VALUES ( Prec, idP, select max(ID_Prod) from Producto )
END
```

Intento obtener el id de una tabla buscando por el nombre del proveedor y almacenarlo y hacer un insert con este en otro tabla pero no se cual es el error de sintaxis o si es algo logico requiero su ayuda porfavor.